# Put figure text under images?

Tags: floats, lyx

In LyX, how can I set a float that contain figure so that the caption is under the figure? By default the caption is always on the left side of figure.

[image]

Comment: The default is for the caption to be either above or below the image/figure (depending on which comes first in the document), not beside it, so you're not using a 'standard' document layout I think. What are you using?

Comment: I thinks it's standard, I only change the document class from article to book since I started writing

Comment: Have you placed the image inside the caption box? It should be outside.

Comment: Now, I don't use `LyX`, but just intalled it. It seems you have inserted the gfx where the caption text should go. Instead you should first add a float container to hold the gfx and the caption. Then there is a nice separation of the two in the interface. Caption should not really be used on its own.

Comment: Oops you're right, I inserted the image where the default cursor located, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Nur for `LyX` questions, please always post a [.lyx minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample). A .tex minimal example would also be helpful.

Comment: got it, i'll include a lyx minimal example on my future question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: MWE]

A figure float in LaTeX is just a `figure` environment (`\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`) but when you make a `figure` float ("flotante" in the capture because the Spanish configuration) in LyX is also created a`\caption{}` command inside (the "`Figure n: [text]`" box) inside. Note that captions are optionals, so you can cut this box to have a figure without legend or even insert more that one caption in the same float.

The images, when translated to LaTeX language are `\includegraphics{imagename}` commands that allowed inside or outside a float. Inside the float, the image could be before or after the caption. Inside a caption, an image is not allowed in LaTeX by default. However, LyX  can force this position including a `\protect` command.

Then you must care of the exact cursor position when inserting images. Insert the `image` inside the float but above or below the `caption` box. When the image was placed in the wrong position, just select only the image, cut it, move the cursor and paste in the right place.

Note that `label` (`\label{}` command in LaTeX) might also  be inserted in any place in a float, but always  place the labels inside or after the caption, never before, in order to avoid wrong cross-references.

With a mouse click then you can control the configuration of the image dimensions. Usually you may want the image centered making a selection with the cursor, and then with a right click selecting center justification. This put in the source code a center environment (`\begin{center}`... `\end{center}`) inside the float, but probably is better make an ERT box at the beginning of the float and write `\centering` (that can produce a different result in terms of vertical spacing).

You can check in the menu `View` that source LaTeX commands are in the correct order. A figure float with `\centering` in an ERT box and the image above the caption, correctly labelled,  should have this order:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{figure}
\caption{\label{fig:The-caption}The caption}
\end{figure}
```