# How change "Figure #" position in lyx

Tags: floats, lyx, captions

I'm using Lyx, and adding a floating image always add a "Figure X" at the left of the image, I'd like to show this 'caption' (I don't know if is caption or not) under the image, how should I do?
What should I add in preamble?

Comment: I notice that Lyx just insert into \caption{} also \includegraphics , but that's I'd like to avoid this, how could I do?

Comment: Just cut the image, put the cursor before "Figure X:[text]" and paste it. This "Figure X:[text]" is just the interpretation of LyX of how the `\caption{text}` command in LaTeX will be showed in the final PDF. That command print `\figurename` ("Figure" by default) plus `\thefigure` (the number) and your caption text. You can redefine that behaviour in your document preamble as in any LaTeX document. There are many examples in this site of how to do.

Comment: Ok! Fran, that was the issue! Never noticed that. Resolved thanks (cut image, put cursor before figure x and paste it)

Comment: Your issue is not clear to me. Please post a screenshot of both the issue in LyX, and the PDF output that you don't like.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think that is answered in [Put figure text under images?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120798/put-figure-text-under-images). Voting to close.